# How to get current date in spring form of jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, date, spring-mvc

Please i want to know how to get the current date in a form of jsp page using spring .Is there a jsp tag for that or maybe a library ? here is my code :

```
    <form:input path="date" value=" " />   </form:form>
```

What should i write in the value to get the current date ?

Thank you ,

Comment: It's better to pass all parameters, including the current date, from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<fmt:formatDate>` tag of JSTL is used to format dates in a variety of ways for a date variable as in below code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>fmt:dateNumber</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Date Format:</h2>
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />

<p>Formatted Date (1): <fmt:formatDate type="time"  value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (2): <fmt:formatDate type="date"  value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (3): <fmt:formatDate type="both" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (4): <fmt:formatDate type="both"  dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short"  value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (5): <fmt:formatDate type="both"  dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="medium" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (6): <fmt:formatDate type="both"  dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long" value="${now}" /></p>
<p>Formatted Date (7): <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${now}" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: dates]

Comment: Ok thank you ! 
But when i try to do like that :

   <form:input path="date" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${now}" />"/>

I get an error

Comment: Whats this?  why are you using value attribute twice? I don't know which type of form you are using but this should work <form action="date">
 <input type="text" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${now}"/>" />
</form>

Comment: I am using the taglib of spring 
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

Comment: So i got this error :
Etat HTTP 500 - /WEB-INF/views/operations.jsp (line: 91, column: 81) equal symbol expected

Comment: There is no value attribute in <form:input  /> tag, please check this. That's why you are getting error.

Comment: may be because of this. can you add the code written on line 91.

Comment: No there is value attribute , because when i write for example this :   
 <form:input path="date" value="10/03/2016"/>
It works !
So here is the line 91 :
   <form:input path="date" value=" <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${now}" />"/>

Thank you Rohit for your precious help !

Answer (score 2):

Try using below code

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
```

In case you want a particular format.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" var="formatted" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it from your controller by using java classes like [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [java.util.GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Here is simple use for class Date.

```
Date date = new Date();
date.toString();
```

what give you String like this.

> Sat Oct 01 21:02:33 AMT 2016

Here is simple use for class GregorianCalendar.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.getTime()
```

What returns you object with type *java.util.Date*
or you can take what property you want with method get like this

```
cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Convert it to String how you want and than pass to your jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
<c:set var="today" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${today}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="todayDate" />
<z:searchDate field="start" label="Tanggal Mulai1" type="datepicker" itemValue="${todayDate}"/>
```